# Copy xml from raw folder to internal storage and use it in android

Tags: java, android, xml, shared-memory, android-resources

I have server.xml inside my raw folder and I want to copy this to my internal storage in the first run of the app.

Then, my app will write to server.xml once in awhile after each run.

to copy server.xml to internal storage my code is :

if ("server.xml") not exists:

```
File file = new File("server.xml");
    try {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        InputStream inputStream =    context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.server);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

        byte buf[]=new byte[1024];
        int len;
        while((len=inputStream.read(buf))>0) {
            fileOutputStream.write(buf,0,len);
        }

        fileOutputStream.close();
        inputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e1) {}
```

now to add to the server.xml

```
documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();       
Document document = documentBuilder.parse("server.xml");
Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
```

but it gives me IOExeption of 
java.net.MalformedURLException: Protocol not found: server.xml

I really appreciate any help. I am very new to android and trying hard get my head around it.

Comment: `File file = new File("server.xml");`. Don't use a relative path. Use an absolute path.

Comment: `Protocol not found: server.xml`. Protocol should be `file://` i think. but `file://server.xml` will not work i also think. Use an absolute path.

Comment: I can create my file like this
 File file = new File(this.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "server.xml");

but still can't open it. 

Any suggestions @greenapps ?

Comment: Well how do you try to open it now? Put the code in your post.

Comment: Try: `new File(context.getFilesDir(), "server.xml");`

Comment: thanks @Guardanis , this gives me the same path as new File(this.getFilesDir() + File.separator + "server.xml") .

How can I open it in  . documentBuilder.parse("server.xml");

this still gives me an exeption

Comment: @greenapps : i want to open it like documentBuilder.parse("server.xml"); but this gives me the exception. 
Could you tell me how to write an xml file and then parse it from internal memory. ?

Comment: You should do the same there too. Use that full path. documentBuilder.parse(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/server.xml");